# When a certain option is selected in a picklist field, we want a validation rule that checks that a task is created for a subsequent date

Tags: validation-rule

When the field “Lead.Status” is set to “A rappeler plus tard”, a validation rule must ensure that this there is a task created for this link to a subsequent date.

When a certain option is selected in a picklist field, we want a validation rule that checks if another field is filled.

When the field “Lead.Status” is set to “Disqualifié”, a validation rule must ensure that this the field “Raison_de_la_disqualification” is filled.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  How far have you got with writing these validation rules yourself?

Comment: from last 2 days am tried with that but not able to write it ...

Comment: As a heads up, this question is likely to be closed as its just posting requirements without showing any attempt or research by you.

Comment: i am new here  so i dont know that attempts is required to show here...ok i will update my attempts image